# Prevenir la creacion de 2 instancia del ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hace poco estoy empezando con WPF y MVVM y se me ha dado el caso en que me sería útil hacer el bindeo del `DataContext` en el Code Behind ya que el ViewModel recibe de parámetro la ventana.

Mi ViewModel tiene un constructor como el siguiente:

```
public ViewModel(Window window)
{
  ...
}
```

Por lo que en el CodeBehind puedo setear el `DataContext` de la siguiente manera

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel(this);
}
```

El problema, es que de esta manera se pierden todas las bondades del IntelliSense para los Bindings, lo que me gustaría evitar.

Intenté crear un constructor por defecto para así bindear en ambos lugares:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>        
</Window.DataContext>
```

Lo cual funcionó sin ningún problema, pero luego note que en realidad se habían creado dos instancias de la clase `ViewModel`.

¿Es posible setear el DataContext dentro de XAML, para así tener IntelliSense, sin que se cree una instancia?

Comment: Yo siempre lo hago por código pero entiendo que haciendolo en cualquiera de los dos sitios debería bastar. Si lo añades en el xaml y no en el codebehind, no te funciona?

Comment: @Pikoh si me funciona, pero no puedo (o aún no descubro como) puedo pasar la instancia de `Window` desde xaml

Comment: Que yo sepa, en XAML no se puede instanciar un viewmodel que tenga un constructor con parámetros.

Comment: @Xam exacto, por eso la idea es instanciarlo en el Code Behind, la respuesta de *Einer* respondió perfectamente a la pregunta!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas creando una instancia en el XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>        
</Window.DataContext>
```

Y tambien en code behind:

```
 DataContext = new ViewModel(this);
```

Por eso te crea 2 instancia de la clase aunque al final solo se utilize una.

Intenta utilizando `d:DataContext` que te permite asignarle un modelo con valores predefinidos a una vista para que puedas previsualizarlo en modo diseño y tambien puedas utilizar el Intellisence en los bindings y no crea una instancia en runtime.

Declara un recurso en tu XAML asignando los valores que desea que muestre en modo diseño:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <local:ViewModel x:Key="Modelo"
        Propiedad1="1"
        Propiedad2="valor"
     />      
</Window.Resources>
```

Entonces en el elemento principal le asignas el contexto de diseño buscandolo con `StaticResource`:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
     <local:ViewModel x:Key="Modelo"
        Propiedad1="1"
        Propiedad2="valor"
     />      
    </Window.Resources>

    <UserControl d:DataContext="{StaticResource Modelo}">
            <!-- Mas elementos... -->
    </UserControl>
</Window>
```

Asi entonces podras utilizar la bondades del Intellisence en los bindings con los controles debajo del elemento donde le declaraste el contexto para modo diseño y previsualizar los valores tambien.

Recuerda que igual tienes que asignar la instancia del DataContext en el code behind para que te funcione en runtime.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, de esta manera no se seguiría creando ambas instancias en runtime?

Comment: No. Tu doble instancia es porque la estas de clarando tambien en el xaml dentro de  `<Window.DataContext>`. Tienes que eliminar esea declaracion para que solo te cree la instancia del code behind

Comment: Genial, ahí entendí,  muchas gracias!